# Bandwidth limiting for import of a large SQL file

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, bash, mariadb

I am trying to import a large MariaDB dump file in a running MariaDB instance (production) without any performance issues. In order to do so i am trying to use cpipe, for a throughput speed limit as below:

`/usr/bin/mysql -uuser -ppass -h host DBname | /usr/bin/cpipe -vr -vw -vt -s 512 -b 1 < /path/to/dump.sql`

It is worth mentioning that the above line is part of a simple bash script, where I specified login credentials + host.

I am receiving contents of `dump.sql` on screen (with the provided limitations) but nothing is actually imported in the MariaDB instance.

What am i doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You inverted the pipe...

```
/usr/bin/cpipe -vr -vw -vt -s 512 -b 1 < /path/to/dump.sql | /usr/bin/mysql -uuser -ppass -h host DBname
```

Comment: This can be handy as well : 
    *cat /path/mybackup.sql 2>&1 | pv -L 3k -q | tee /dev/tty | mysql*

Comment: Don't use `cat` for a single file, you earn a UUCA... `pv -L 3k -q < /path/mybackup.sql | tee /dev/tty | mysql`

Comment: Yeah i've used redirection originally, not sure why changes to cat. What is UUCA, just curious? Don't know what it is.

Comment: Oh i actually deciphered "UUCA",  - useless use of cat award, used redirection originally, changed to cat probably for more visual example. Thanks for edit.